# How to get segregated x and y values in python args?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def makes_twenty(*args):
    for x,y in args:
        return x

makes_twenty(20,50,2)
```

I have written a function above. I gave three arguments and want to fetch two arguments in the variables x and y. however at the exact for loop line I get the following error and I am unable to understand why:

```
    for x,y in args:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

How can I fetch the values of args in the form of different variables using the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

`for x,y in args:` expects `args` to be a sequence of pairs, but `args` is a sequence of single integers (the tuple `(20, 50, 2)`); therefore, it can't unpack a single integer into two variables.

You could do the following, which will extract the first two arguments into `x` and `y` and any remaining arguments into `z`:

```py
def makes_twenty(*args):
    x,y,*z = args
    return x

print(makes_twenty(20,50,2))
```

Output:

```
20
```

Answer (score 1):

You `args` value is a tuple with `(20, 50, 2)` If you iterate in your `args` variable the first element should be `20` the second `50` and the third `2`

So when you try to iterate as `for x,y in args:` in the first iteration, the value is `20` but you are trying to unpack 2 variables when there is only one, so it throws an error.

You can do something like

```
def makes_twenty(*args):
    x,y, _ = args

print(makes_twenty(20,50,2))
```

You can see a `_` this is usually using for unpack a variable that it will not be used.